# What does a deterministic MAC actually mean?

Tags: mac, pseudo-random-function

Does a MAC that's deterministic mean it uses a PRF? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Welcome to Cryptography,SE. Where did you see that? What is the origin of this question? A hint, see probabilistic encryption.

Comment: @kelalaka I saw this in the Katz-Lindell textbook, question 4.8. It asks for a MAC construction that is deterministic, but doesn't rely on a PRF. I am just also wondering how one would prove that the deterministic MAC without a PRF is secure via reduction.

Comment: Not sure, we haven't really covered those in class.

Comment: You will see in section 4.5 GMAC and Poly1305

Comment: A deterministic MAC is one such that for a given key and message, the authenticator output by the MAC is always the same. That the case if the MAC is implemented by a deterministic algorithm and without an explicit random input.